# Missing dependency with version 0.9.3 and 0.9.4

Tags: karate

I was trying the lastest version of karate, but maven can't retrieve `com.intuit.karate:karate-netty:jar:0.9.4`. Any advice?

```
[INFO] ---------------------< integration-test >---------------------
[INFO] Building integration-test 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-junit4/0.9.4/karate-junit4-0.9.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-junit4/0.9.4/karate-junit4-0.9.4.pom (1.9 kB at 1.3 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-parent/0.9.4/karate-parent-0.9.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-parent/0.9.4/karate-parent-0.9.4.pom (6.8 kB at 88 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-core/0.9.4/karate-core-0.9.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-core/0.9.4/karate-core-0.9.4.pom (4.9 kB at 66 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.pom (38 kB at 262 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-apache/0.9.4/karate-apache-0.9.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-apache/0.9.4/karate-apache-0.9.4.pom (1.7 kB at 23 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-netty/0.9.4/karate-netty-0.9.4.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.intuit.karate:karate-netty:jar:0.9.4 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-junit4/0.9.4/karate-junit4-0.9.4.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-netty/0.9.4/karate-netty-0.9.4.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-apache/0.9.4/karate-apache-0.9.4.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-core/0.9.4/karate-core-0.9.4.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-junit4/0.9.4/karate-junit4-0.9.4.jar (8.0 kB at 28 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-apache/0.9.4/karate-apache-0.9.4.jar (24 kB at 79 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.jar (303 kB at 794 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/karate-core/0.9.4/karate-core-0.9.4.jar (3.4 MB at 5.3 MB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.272 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-25T14:35:58+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project integration-test: Could not resolve dependencies for project it.govpay:integration-test:jar:1: Could not find artifact com.intuit.karate:karate-netty:jar:0.9.4 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read the release notes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.3

There is no more `karate-netty`, `karate-core` has all you need.

Comment: but it is still listed as dependency in https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-gatling/pom.xml

Comment: @linuxfan in `test` scope for the developers